# Determinant Value For Very Large Matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, determinants

I have a very large square matrix of order around 100000 and I want to know whether the determinant value is zero or not for that matrix.

What can be the fastest way to know that ?

I have to implement that in C++

Comment: Find yourself a good BLAS implementation, and call the functions it gives you.

Comment: thats around 80GB to store that matrix, you may wanna rethink your approach.

Comment: It is better to use existent mathematical libraries for such tasks, because it is already tested. So do not implement your own determentant function for it! Also, it is very hard problem to calculate determenant for so big matrix. Are you sure, that you really need it?

Comment: @Ilya well, OP does not need to calculate it. He wants know if it's zero or not. This is quite different problem. Calculating it is one solution. Not the best most probably.

Comment: still, regardless, using existing libraries is very good advice.

Comment: Actually I have homogeneous set of n equations and I want to know whether or not it has the trivial solution 0 for all its n variables where n is around 10^5

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to determine if the matrix is non-singular you may want to look here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-determine-if-a-matrix-is-invertible

As mentioned in the comments its best to use some sort of BLAS library that will do this for you such as `Boost::uBLAS`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, matrices of that size are extremely sparse. Use row and column reordering algorithms to concentrate the entries near the diagonal and then use a QR decomposition or LU decomposition. The product of the diagonal entries of the second factor is - up to a sign in the QR case - the determinant. This may still be too ill-conditioned, the best result for rank is obtained by performing a singular value decomposition. However, SVD is more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property that if any two rows are equal or one row is a constant multiple of another row we can say that determinant of that matrix is zero.It is applicable to columns as well.

Comment: This is simply a statement that doesn't actually serve to answer the original poster's question. I suggest you read over [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) and reformulate your answer.

Comment: @r3mus Thank you,if you implement the above statement difficulty is less than o(n!) as mentioned in this link at [math.stack] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-determine-if-a-matrix-is-invertible)

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge your application doesnt need to calculate determinant but the rank of matrix is sufficient to check if system of equations have non-trivial solution : -

[Rank of Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29)